# change dimension of webpage

Tags: html, xhtml

How to change dimension of a webpage. I want to build a mobile website and thus the width should not be greater than 320. Is there any way to change dimension.
Also what should be the steps to build a mobile website.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a fixed width layout like the 960 grid system?

You have two options:

- Build a separate 'mobile' version of your whole website, and switch to that by detecting the phone in the HTTP headers.
- Use a fluid design, so your website design can squeeze into any space you put it into.

If you choose the latter, take a look at http://cssgrid.net/ - this allows your website to fit onto large widescreens **and** tiny mobile screens, with only one design!

Comment: I am building separate mobile version and for that only i want to reduce dimension of webpage.

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer. By making a table of desired width. Working perfectly.

Comment: If you are writing a entirely new site, why are you using an outdated table layout?

Comment: Then what are your suggestions??

Comment: table based designs should be used for table only, nothing else. I suspect RoToRa, including myself, would advocate valid XHTML/CSS to build a movile website. For starters you could wrap all your content in a div with a width of 320px... Really simple :)